# why does a new page open when the url doesn't match the content loaded

Tags: security, url, browser, hyperlink, request

TLDR:

When a page's content is from one site (`npr.com`), but the url bar was loaded with another address (`yahoo.com`), why does clicking on a link in the page open a new browser, when if they match (content from npr.com and loaded from npr.com url) they don't?

I had an old habit (10+ years) of typing yahoo.com to get new content to check if my internet is working.  Now I would rather use npr.com, but it is quite difficult to change that habit, so I changed the hosts file `/etc/hosts` (OSX)

```
216.35.221.76 yahoo.com
216.35.221.76 www.yahoo.com
216.35.221.76 https://www.yahoo.com
```

so that any time I type `yah` then `Enter` with the autocomplete from the browser, it goes to NPR's site, but the URL remains whatever version of yahoo.com that was autocompleted from the browser.   Witha quick glance, all the content appears the same (as does the source code), but the url bar has a different URI than npr.com or http://www.npr.com or the like.

But when I click on a link of a Yahoo/NPR link, it opens in a new tab, not changing in the same tab as if it was just an unadulterated NPR page.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that for this domain, the author has setup a script that automatically adds `target="_blank"` for links that don't match the current domain name. This is not default behavior.